# I want to pass data from my child component(state) to parent component on select some item from a search bar

Tags: reactjs

I have crated an search bar component which gets data on the basis on input and show it in the list down below what i want is while selecting the searched result i want to send the data to the parent component to send that data to backend any help would be much appreciated, my code is as below

Child component is as below

```
this.state = {
        products: [],
        ProductId: '',
        ProductName: '',
        ProductSubName: ''
    } 

   handleDetails = async (item) => {
    this.setState({
        ProductName: item.Description,
        ProductId: item._id,
        ProductSubName: item['Sub Description 2'],
        products: [],
    }, () => {
        this.props.update()
    })
}

render(){
        return(
            <Box>
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        id="search"
                        name="productName"
                        placeholder={'Search Product Here'}
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.ProductName ? this.state.ProductSubName ? this.state.ProductName + '' + this.state.ProductSubName : this.state.ProductName : this.state.search ? this.state.search : ''}
                    >
                    </Input>
                    <Button                        
                        onClick={this.handleSearch}
                    >
                        Search
                        </Button>

 <ProductList>
                    {this.state.products.map(item => {
                        let index = this.state.products.indexOf(item)
                        return (
                            <ProductItem
                                key={item._id}
                                onClick={() => this.handleDetails(item)}
                                className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd'}
                            >
                                {item.Description}
                            </ProductItem>
                        )
                    })}
                </ProductList>
```

Now what i want is on handleDetails i want to send productId from the state of the above child component to parent component

parent Component is as below

```
import Search from 'component'

render(){
return(
   <Search> </Search>
)
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a callback function to the child from the parent

Parent

```
import Search from 'component'

handleChildChange = productId => {
  // do whatever you want with productId
}

render(){
return(
   <Search onChildChange={this.handleChildChange}> </Search>
)
```

Child

```
handleDetails = async (item) => {
    this.setState({...})
    this.props.onChildChange(item._id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this.

```
import Search from 'component'
const handleUpdate = (e) => {
   console.log(e);
}
render(){
return(
   <Search update={this.handleInput}> </Search>
)
```

and on your child component,

```
() => {
    this.props.update(e)
}
```